# Modal is not showing buttons

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

First time poster so forgive me for any breaks in tradition.

I am working on a modal for my bootcamp.

- The modal is inside of a button that, once clicked, brings up the modal.
- Inside of the modal is a form (with select tags) that needs to show
  the number of campers, the date, and a tent/RV button.

For whatever reason, none of the labels or buttons are showing when the modal is brought up (only the date and campers input). Initially, I thought it was because I had a tooltip on the same button (which I removed), but that did not help. I'm almost certain its a div or closing tag I'm missing but for the life of me I can't find it. **Edited with additional HTML**

```
<span class="navbar-text ml-auto">
  <a role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">
    <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>Login
  </a>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
<!-- Modal fade effect will give it a subtle looks -->
<div id="reserveModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header bg-info text-white">
  <h3 class="modal-title">Reserve a Campsite</h3>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <form>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="numCampers" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Number of Campers</label>
            <div class="col">
              <select name="numCampers" class="form-control" id="numcampers">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="date" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">
              <input type="date" id="date" name="date" class="form-control" placeholder="date"/>
            </div>
          </div>
            <!-- Radio buttons -->
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Campsite Type</label>
              <div class="col btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="button">Tent</div>
              <div class="col btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="button">RV</div>
            </div> 

<div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn bg-primary text-white">Search</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome. It's a bit troublesome, in my experience,to mix grid classes with form structure classes. I'd seek to keep them separate. Also, rows should have only columns as a children. The margins on each are configured to work together. Also also, you should have this question tagged with a specific Bootstrap version since its CSS classes play a significant role. Finally, your HTML is truncated. The conclusion of that snippet may be important.

Comment: Please modify your question to include ALL the html to the end of the modal div.

Comment: Have revised, let me know if any additional information is required. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: `data-target="#loginModal"`, but you have not shown us that modal. There are also some unbalanced tags (`<div>`, `<nav>`).

Comment: Try creating a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), eg [here's a jsFiddle to get started](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/0j3p8scg/).

Comment: You marked this as jQuery and bootstrap-modal but show none of that code, we will be very challenged to answer how to fix your code when we have none to see.

Comment: As I mentioned your code is showing us the wrong modal - or is is `loginModal` actually supposed to be `reserveModal`?